# Dateformat ww returns wrong week of year

Tags: coldfusion

Can someone explain why getting the week of this date returns 1 instead of 53? And how do I get coldfusion to return 53 for this date?

```
<cfscript>
    Date1 = "{ts '2019-12-30  12:00:00'}";
    dateformat= DateFormat(Date1)
    week= DateFormat(Date1,"ww")
    writeOutput("Week: " & week & "<br/>")
</cfscript>
```

See the coldfusion fiddle: https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=ab0d50c0-d268-4769-b5eb-a16a8fca985a/dc6aebb2-76a8-4485-a5eb-e9eb17b293cb/9e6e8b2c-f570-45be-88a1-49db39f8c69b.cfm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`week(Date)`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/week.html) instead of trying `dateformat`.

I am not sure why `dateformat` is taking the last week of 2019 as the first week of 2020. Most likely `dateformat` is not designed to handles these nuanced logics. Since `Week` function is must be specifically designed for this purpose it would be wise to make use of that. I'll update the answer if I can find anything specific to suggest the reason for `dateformat` issue.

Update from comment by @Agreax :

`Week()` uses Adobe's internal logic. `DateFormat()` uses java's `SimpleDateFormat` class which [".. depends on the values of getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(), getFirstDayOfWeek(), and the day of the week of January 1.."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_and_year). With the default settings, 12/30/2019 is considered part of the 1st week of 2020.

Comment: Do you also know why dateformat returns 1 instead of 53?

Comment: I am not sure, but it will be an interesting thing to look into.

Comment: Week() uses Adobe's internal logic. DateFormat() uses java's SimpleDateFormat class which [".. depends on the values of getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(), getFirstDayOfWeek(), and the day of the week of January 1.."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_and_year).  With the default settings, 12/30/2019 is considered part of the 1st week of **2020**. https://trycf.com/gist/e1e27f379762aa0c1ff0e69d566d2c3c/acf2018?theme=monokai